# Fill database model with selfmade form in bulk Django

Tags: python, django, forms

Using the 2 images below as reference you can see that one image has 3 matches and the other has only 1 match. This is just a call to the **encuesta model table** that brings all the matches for that day.

A user can save their answers of the available matches on **respuestas model table**.

The grid you se on the images had been made by hand on the template side with no {{form}} just iterating the query result and adding this fields.

What i need is just send the available fields to model respuestas to create new rows with the answers for the matches user thinks will result in the future.

[image]

[image]

This should be the equivalent fields for the 2 images above, in other words the values shown in the grid should be saved as new rows on that model table (respuestas)

[image]

Here is my models.py

```
class equipo(models.Model):

nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
bandera = StdImageField(upload_to='bandera/%Y/%m/%d',
                        variations={
                        'large':(53,53, False),
                        'thumbnail': (70, 26, False)})

GRUPOS = (
    ('A', 'Grupo A'),
    ('B', 'Grupo B'),
    ('C', 'Gropo C'),
    ('D', 'Gropo D'),
    ('E', 'Gropo E'),
    ('F', 'Gropo F'),
    ('G', 'Gropo G'),
    ('H', 'Gropo H'),
)

grupo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GRUPOS)

def banderaEquipo(self):
    return '<img src="/media/%s">' % (self.bandera.thumbnail)

banderaEquipo.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre


class encuesta(models.Model):

equipoA = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoA')
golesEquipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
equipoB = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoB')
golesEquipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)

ETAPA = (
    ('1', 'Primera Etapa'),
    ('2', 'Octavos De Final'),
    ('3', 'Cuartos De Final'),
    ('4', 'Semifinal'),
    ('5', 'Final'),
    ('6', '3ra Posicion')
)

etapa = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ETAPA)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s Vs. %s" % (unicode(self.equipoA), unicode(self.equipoB))


class respuesta(models.Model):

encuesta = models.ForeignKey(encuesta)
empresa = models.ForeignKey(empresa)
empleado = models.ForeignKey(empleado)
equipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
equipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s" % (unicode(self.encuesta))
```

Comment: I have been searching on the internet and found this but dont know if there is a better way to do it. def handle(request):
2     if request.method == 'POST':
3          artists = request.POST.getlist('artists') I'm learning but wanna do it right :) want to use form.is_valid() and then form.save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you're looking for [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). Formsets allow you to display and validate a form on many pieces of data at once.

Comment: as you see. the fields and flags can be from 0 to 10 and varies by hour. I need to pass like you do on PHP teamA[] teamB[] userID[] and save it on the Database. but before it gets saved forms.is_valid(): should run... see what i mean??

Comment: Actually I can't see that it could be from 0 to 10 (despite that, your question says "1 to 10 ... on date"). Please update the question to make it clear what you are trying to achieve. Please read the docs I linked to and tell me how this does not solve your needs.

Comment: Updated the question, hope its better now, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Yep. This is exactly what formset were designed to solve. Read the docs for creating formsets, especially look at using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory.

Comment: Thank you i solved the problem. It took me some time but i've  found a tutorial online http://stellarchariot.com/blog/2011/02/dynamically-add-form-to-formset-using-javascript-and-django/ this really help me figure it out.